# What is happening when my() is conditional?

Tags: perl

Compare using  `perl -w -Mstrict`:

```
# case Alpha
print $c;
```

...

```
# case Bravo
if (0) {
  my $c = 1;
}

print $c;
```

...

```
# case Charlie
my $c = 1 if 0;
print $c;
```

`Alpha` and `Bravo` both complain about the global symbol not having an explicit package name, which is to be expected. But `Charlie` does not give the same warning, only that the value is uninitialized, which smells a lot like:

```
# case Delta
my $c;
print $c;
```

What exactly is going on under the hood? (Even though something like this should never be written for production code)

Comment: In the Bravo case, `$c` is lexically scoped to the `if (0) ...` block, and it is an error (under `use strict`) to refer to it outside that block.

Comment: By the way, the behaviour of `my $c = 1 if 0; ... $c ...` is officially undefined (and documented as such), meaning its not allowed and can result in undesired behaviour (e.g. crashing). Well, it won't crash, but it could :)

Comment: @ikegami hmm you're totally right it's listed under the "statement modifiers" section of perlsyn. good reminder!

Comment: @Andrew regurgitating perl best practices doesn't actually answer the question. also, if you read the first line of the question, warnings and strict are already active

Comment: [After v5.30, you can no longer do this](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2019/07/no-more-false-postfix-lexical-declarations-in-v5-30/)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can think of a `my` declaration as having an action at compile-time and at run-time. At compile-time, a `my` declaration tells the compiler to make a note that a symbol exists and will be available until the end of the current lexical scope. An assignment or other use of the symbol in that declaration will take place at run-time.

So your example

```
my $c = 1 if 0;
```

is like

```
my $c;         # compile-time declaration, initialized to undef
$c = 1 if 0;   # runtime -- as written has no effect
```

---

Note that this compile-time/run-time distinction allows you to write code like this.

```
my $DEBUG;    # lexical scope variable declared at compile-time
BEGIN {
    $DEBUG = $ENV{MY_DEBUG};   # statement executed at compile-time
};
```

Now can you guess what the output of this program is?

```
my $c = 3;
BEGIN {
    print "\$c is $c\n";
    $c = 4;
}
print "\$c is $c\n";
```

Comment: An AMAZING answer! The compile-time distinction was the missing key. Many thanks!

Comment: `my` does have a run-time effect as you say, but you didn't mention what it is! [It places a directive on the stack to clear the variable on scope exit, then it returns the var as an lvalue.] Ok, it's probably for the best that you didn't mention that. :)

Answer (score 8):

[mob's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11268473/18914) is a great explanation of what currently happens (and why), but don't forget that [`perldoc perlsyn`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Statement-Modifiers) tells us:

> **NOTE:** The behaviour of a `my`, `state`, or `our` modified with a statement modifier conditional or loop construct (for example, `my $x
>   if ...` ) is **undefined**. The value of the `my` variable may be
>   `undef`, any previously assigned value, or possibly anything else.
>   Don't rely on it. Future versions of perl might do something different
>   from the version of perl you try it out on. Here be dragons.

Don't count on that result or the explanation for it still being true in future versions of Perl.  (Although it probably will be.)

Answer (score 3):

The "my $foo = *val* if *cond*" construct and its undefined behavior has bitten me many times over the years. I wish the compiler could simply reject it (why keep something in the language that has undefined behavior?!), but presumably this cannot be done for backward compatibility or other reasons. Best solution I've found is to prevent it with perlcritic:

http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Perl::Critic::Policy::Variables::ProhibitConditionalDeclarations

Comment: Perlcritic is never the best solution to anything.

Comment: What alternative do I have, if I want to prevent this toxic construct from ever being accidentally used?