# Perl regex to get data from line

Tags: regex, perl

I have a data in scalar variable and I want to divide the data into 2 parts based on certain condition.
Data is:

```
50This is my test data;and this line is for testing.
```

I want this to be stored in 2 separate variables and result should be:

```
$first = 50
$second = This is my test data;and this line is for testing.
```

This is what I have tried, but in single expression how to achieve this?

```
my $first = $1 if ($line =~ /(\d+)This/);
my $second = $2 if ($line =~ /(\d+)(\w+)/)
```

Comment: `my $x = .. if ..` https://stackoverflow.com/a/11275324/223226

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is slightly simpler than the two solutions you already have.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $data = '50This is my test data;and this line is for testing.';

my ($first, $second) = $data =~ /^(\d+)(.*)/ or die "No pattern match";

say "first:  $first";
say "second: $second";
```

Comment: Also, the variables should be named more descriptively by the OP.

Comment: @TimurShtatland: I agree completely. But as I know nothing about the data, it would be impossible for me to make that change.

Comment: @Dave Cross Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

`(\d+)([\s\S]+)`

Number is in the first capturing group, remaining sentence in the second.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oSVlS8/8)

Comment: Why `[\s\S]` instead of just `.`?

Comment: `.` won't consider `\n`

Comment: If that's important (and I'm not sure it is here) then using `/s` on the match operator is a better way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this:

```
my $line = "50This is my test data;and this line is for testing.";

my ($first, $second) = ($line=~m/(\d+)([^\n]*)$/g);

print "$first\t$second\n";
```

Comment: `[^\n]*` is the same as `.*` (as long as you're not using `/s`). And the final `$` is unnecessary as regexes are greedy by default.

Comment: If they matching regex line by line then we need check `!\n - ([^\n]*)$`